# Using lodash or a similar library, how do you sort collections by closest result?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, lodash

I have an array of objects and I'm filtering our these objects based on the user input. Now what I'd like to do is sort the objects by closest matching.

```
_internalSearch = (input) => {
    const { data } = this.props;

    const filteredData = _.filter(data, (collection) => {
      const subCollection = _.pick(collection, ["name", "alias"];
      return _.includes(
        subCollection.toString().toLowerCase(), 
        input.toString().toLowerCase()
      ); 
    });

    //psudo code: 
    /**
    return _.sortBy( items-by-closest-matching-search )
    */

}
```

Where data looks something like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Guide",
        "url": "http://gify.net",
        "alias": "Maps"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Summa",
        "alias": "Fun Town"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mars",
        "url": "https://funstuff.org",
        "alias": "Dentist"
    }
]
```

Now if the input is `ma` all three results show, which is good, but I would like to sort these results by closest-matching by name. So the results would be in the order:
`Mars, Summa, Guide`

I guess the process would be:

1) Sort alphabetically (optional)

2) Sort on "alias" by distance of substring from start of string

3) Sort on "name" by distance of substring from start of string

Comment: for #2 and #3 you can use levenshtein distance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out myself. The solution is pretty simple.

I ended up caring to sort the aliases and found that sorting on name was plenty. Sorting on aliases increased my computational complexity for, in my use case, practically no gain.

```
sortResults = (data, input) => {
  _.sortBy(data, [
    ({ name }) => {
      const index = name.indexOf(input);
      return index === -1 ? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER : index;
    }
  ]);
};
```

Comment: What if we need to ordered that result by similarity ? How can we implement it ?